# Using a timer to create and draw object on a specific time interval

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create and draw an object from my class every 3 seconds, and the objects would appear on the screen on random coordinates,and when i click one of the objects it would be removed.

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for Stackoverflow. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people can show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

This is simple timer initialization with `Interval` of 3 seconds. In the event handle drawing new objects.

```
//timer initialization 
var t = new Timer();
t.Tick += TimerEventProcessor;
t.Interval = 3000;
t.Start();


//event
private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
   //your drawing code
}
```